# Download File to server from URL

Tags: php, http, stream, download

Well, this one seems quite simple, and it is. All you have to do to download a file to your server is:

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", file_get_contents("http://someurl/file.zip"));
```

Only there is one problem. What if you have a large file, like 100mb. Then, you will run out of memory, and not be able to download the file.

What I want is a way to write the file to the disk as I am downloading it. That way, I can download bigger files, without running into memory problems.

Comment: That's set in your server configuration, PHP can't really get around it as far as I know (except for a direct .ini edit)

Answer (score 580, accepted):

Since PHP 5.1.0, [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) supports writing piece-by-piece by passing a stream-handle as the `$data` parameter:

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
```

From the manual:

> If ***data*** [that is the second argument] is a stream resource, the remaining buffer of that stream will be copied to the specified file. This is similar with using
>   [`stream_copy_to_stream()`](http://php.net/stream_copy_to_stream).

(Thanks [Hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367456/hakre).)

Comment: That wouldn't be my first choice. If `allow_fopen_url Off` is set in php.ini (good idea for security), your script would be broken.

Comment: @idealmachine I think `file_get_contents()` would not work either if that were the case (see OP).

Comment: @alex: Please see the edit, feel free to incorporate. let me know when I can remove this comment here then.

Comment: @hakre Thanks, much appreciated. I'll make it flow a bit easier. :)

Comment: The 'b' flag should also be used in most cases with `fopen`; prevents adverse effects to images and other non plain text files.

Comment: thanks this saved my 1GB of mobile data i was planning transfering file from one server to another, i could directly moved zip file instead of downloading and uploading to new server. :)

Comment: Would this approach be better than using `curl`?

Answer (score 141):

```
private function downloadFile($url, $path)
{
    $newfname = $path;
    $file = fopen ($url, 'rb');
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen ($newfname, 'wb');
        if ($newf) {
            while(!feof($file)) {
                fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8), 1024 * 8);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }
    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank's for your snippit, but would you be able to explain your code @xaav? I'm not exactly brilliant at php.

What is 1024*8 for ? Thank's again.

Comment: @wMINOw The length of the line.

Comment: Specifically, it means to read up to 8KB at a time (1024 bytes per KB * 8) since the parameter is in bytes.  As long as the line is <= 8KB, it will read the entire line at once.

Comment: Why is not this the best answer?

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: How do you handle errors with this approach? What if a 404 is returned or the connection is interrupted or times out?

Comment: That would be useful, but if 404 goes through you would be downloading anything, and you can always run a search check for that file (some logic) if (!myfile) -> break;

Comment: Best way to download large files

Comment: Magnificently fast - you r true maestro!

Comment: sometimes the `fopen failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` show this error because of web crawling prevention how to resolve it? @<xaav> @<Ibrahim Azhar Armar>

Comment: NomanJaved you need to do auth request on a login form first and reuse the same curl client (or at least it's headers and cookie) for all further requests.

Comment: How it downloads without CURL ?

Comment: Downloads 0KB empty file although the file is more than 17MB Skype main.db file. On PHP 5.4 also had to remove "private" from the beginning of the function.

Comment: This solution was very nice for me, because I had to download a huge XML file which exceeds my PHP memory_limit if 1024M.

Comment: How is this different/better from the answer with `fopen`?

Comment: `Note`: The $path should include the name of the file you want to create. `Example: $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/' . "test.mp3";`

Answer (score 74):

Try using cURL

```
set_time_limit(0); // unlimited max execution time
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_FILE    => '/path/to/download/the/file/to.zip',
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800, // set this to 8 hours so we dont timeout on big files
  CURLOPT_URL     => 'http://remoteserver.com/path/to/big/file.zip',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm not sure but I believe with the `CURLOPT_FILE` option it writes as it pulls the data, ie. not buffered.

Comment: Normally, this would be fine, but I have this code in a web app, so I cant be sure users will have cURL installed. However, I did give this a vote up.

Comment: @Geoff is it a distributed web app? Because if you control the hosting, then it doesn't matter about your users (cURL is a library on your server).

Comment: No. I do not control hosting. It is a distributed web app that anyone could have.

Comment: Curl might be missing. But almost all shared hosting companies have CURL installed by default. I mean, I haven't seen one that doesn't.

Comment: As from my tests, you can't assign to CURLOPT_FILE a file path directly. It has to be a file handler. First, open the file with `$fh = fopen('/path/to/download/the/file/to.zip', 'w');` and close with `fclose($fh);` after `curl_close($ch);`. And set `CURLOPT_FILE => $fh`

Answer (score 29):

prodigitalson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url/3938564#3938564) didn't work for me. I got `missing fopen in CURLOPT_FILE` [more details](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?268299-RESOLVED-PHP-script-for-a-cronjob-download-file-unpzck-run-another-php-script).

This worked for me, including local urls:

```
function downloadUrlToFile($url, $outFileName)
{   
    if(is_file($url)) {
        copy($url, $outFileName); 
    } else {
        $options = array(
          CURLOPT_FILE    => fopen($outFileName, 'w'),
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT =>  28800, // set this to 8 hours so we dont timeout on big files
          CURLOPT_URL     => $url
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $httpcode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

1. Create a folder called "downloads" in destination server
2. Save [this code] into `.php` file and run in destination server

#### Downloader :

```
<html>
<form method="post">
<input name="url" size="50" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
    // maximum execution time in seconds
    set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);

    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) die();

    // folder to save downloaded files to. must end with slash
    $destination_folder = 'downloads/';

    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $newfname = $destination_folder . basename($url);

    $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
    if ($file) {
      $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

      if ($newf)
      while(!feof($file)) {
        fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
      }
    }

    if ($file) {
      fclose($file);
    }

    if ($newf) {
      fclose($newf);
    }
?>
</html>
```

Comment: This assumes the user wants a standalone script rather than a solution that will work within an existing PHP application, and I believe the latter is what the OP and most others are looking for. An explanation would also be helpful for people who want to understand the approach.

Comment: whenever I try this always my transferred file size is 50816 but my file size is bigger than this.. 120MB.. Any idea why is this?

Comment: `set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);` has to be put inside a loop. It has no effect at the beginning of the script.

Comment: How to download from this url: https://filehippo.com/download_mozilla-firefox-64/post_download/

Answer (score 18):

```
set_time_limit(0); 
$file = file_get_contents('path of your file');
file_put_contents('file.ext', $file);
```

Comment: your answer is very simple and good working, helped me where cURL failed to get file, this worked. Thanks :)

Comment: You might want to explain what this actually does.

Comment: This does not address the OP's problem of exceeding the PHP memory limit.

Comment: This is pretty simple and straightforward. Quite useful for simpler cases where the files are small or the the environment is a local development.

Comment: any idea for .xlsx files ? It's storing empty file with 0 byte memory .

Answer (score 12):

Use a simple method in php `copy()`

```
copy($source_url, $local_path_with_file_name);
```

Note: if the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten

[PHP copy() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_copy.asp)

Note: You need to set permission 777 for the destination folder.
Use this method when you are downloading to your local machine.

Special Note: **777 is a permission in Unix based system with full read/write/execute permission to owner, group and everyone.** In general we give this permission to assets which are not much needed to be hidden from public on a web server. Example: images folder.

Comment: I will never never never set 777 as perms on a webserver, and I will kick off any webdeveloper whom has the bad idea to do that. Every time, everywhere. Be carefull ! You can not do that ! Think about security. Following OWASP rules is not enough. Having good thinking about simple things matters.

Comment: @ThierryB. Note: I've given local path. & this can be used in internal applications. Having good reading and understanding of question and answer matters. Think different scenarios. And this is not accepted/best answer. Every question has different answers with pros & cons in it.. Example for you to understand: Even Fibonacci have multiple unique solutions where only one will be best. Others will be used in different scenarios.

Comment: Ok, but taking time to think about best practises and implement them inside secured places will give you a better understanding of concepts you must implement. Maybe if an intruder is inside your ($)home, doing some traps or building things the best way you can will give him some headaches ;)

Answer (score 9):

There are 3 ways:

1. file_get_contents and file_put_contents
2. CURL
3. fopen

You can find examples [from here](http://4rapiddev.com/php/download-image-or-file-from-url/).

Answer (score 5):

I use this to download file

```
function cURLcheckBasicFunctions()
{
  if( !function_exists("curl_init") &&
      !function_exists("curl_setopt") &&
      !function_exists("curl_exec") &&
      !function_exists("curl_close") ) return false;
  else return true;
}

/*
 * Returns string status information.
 * Can be changed to int or bool return types.
 */
function cURLdownload($url, $file)
{
  if( !cURLcheckBasicFunctions() ) return "UNAVAILABLE: cURL Basic Functions";
  $ch = curl_init();
  if($ch)
  {

    $fp = fopen($file, "w");
    if($fp)
    {
      if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url) )
      {
        fclose($fp); // to match fopen()
        curl_close($ch); // to match curl_init()
        return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_URL)";
      }
      if ((!ini_get('open_basedir') && !ini_get('safe_mode')) || $redirects < 1) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071204 Ubuntu/7.10 (gutsy) Firefox/2.0.0.11');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://domain.com/');
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $curlopt_header)) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER)";
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $redirects > 0)) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION)";
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FILE)";
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, $redirects) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS)";

        return curl_exec($ch);
    } else {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071204 Ubuntu/7.10 (gutsy) Firefox/2.0.0.11');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://domain.com/');
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false)) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION)";
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FILE)";
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true)) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER)";
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true)) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER)";
        if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, false)) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE)";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071204 Ubuntu/7.10 (gutsy) Firefox/2.0.0.11');
    }
      // if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION)";
      // if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_FILE)";
      // if( !curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0) ) return "FAIL: curl_setopt(CURLOPT_HEADER)";
      if( !curl_exec($ch) ) return "FAIL: curl_exec()";
      curl_close($ch);
      fclose($fp);
      return "SUCCESS: $file [$url]";
    }
    else return "FAIL: fopen()";
  }
  else return "FAIL: curl_init()";
}
```

Comment: How to downlod from this url: https://filehippo.com/download_mozilla-firefox-64/post_download/

Answer (score 4):

**A PHP 4 & 5 Solution:**

**readfile()** will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own.
A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: This does not answer the question, because the question is about writing on disk not to the output buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
<?php 
exec('wget http://someurl/file.zip');
```

Comment: @Netwons make sure wget  available in your server.

Comment: wget available to system     error  ======>   errorCode=1 SSL/TLS handshake failure: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.

Comment: or error ======>   Connecting to www.you.com (www.you.com)|178.79.180.188|:443... connected.

Answer (score 0):

**best solution**

> install aria2c in system &

```
 echo exec("aria2c \"$url\"")
```