# Need php script to download a file on a remote server and save locally

Tags: php, download

Trying to download a file on a remote server and save it to a local subdirectory.

The following code seems to work for small files, < 1MB, but larger files just time out and don't even begin to download.

```
<?php

 $source = "http://someurl.com/afile.zip";
 $destination = "/asubfolder/afile.zip";

 $data = file_get_contents($source);
 $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
 fputs($file, $data);
 fclose($file);

?>
```

Any suggestions on how to download larger files without interruption?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have curl on the system hosting the script.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = "http://someurl.com/afile.zip";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "/asubfolder/afile.zip";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying it now but it seems that the browser hangs.

Comment: @bigLarry you gotta wait for the file to download, the browser might hang till the download finishes. Try with a medium size file which will finish faster but is big enough to hit the timeout

Comment: For bigger files use this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/3938564/1057527](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3938564/1057527)

Comment: Better one-line solution below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726077/179571

Comment: When I run this I get the file to show up, but with a size of 0KB. The other methods give me bad address errors or 502 Gateway issues. Any ideas?

Comment: How to download files with this URL: https://filehippo.com/download_mozilla-firefox-64/post_download/

Answer (score 5):

`file_get_contents` shouldn't be used for big binary files because you can easily hit PHP's memory limit. I would `exec()` `wget` by telling it the URL and the desired output filename:

```
exec("wget $url -O $filename");
```

Comment: It is very useful on hosts that support SSH. Just if you want to get some file from remote server to another server `wget http://public-url-of-the-file`

Comment: What about the URL like this? : https://filehippo.com/download_mozilla-firefox-64/post_download/

Answer (score 5):

**Since PHP 5.1.0, file_put_contents() supports writing piece-by-piece by passing a stream-handle as the $data parameter:**

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
```

Comment: This is an AWESOME solution - works fast and simple - THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

I always use this code,it's working very well.

```
<?php
define('BUFSIZ', 4095);
$url = 'Type The URL Of The File';
$rfile = fopen($url, 'r');
$lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'w');
while(!feof($rfile))
fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);
fclose($rfile);
fclose($lfile);
?>
```

Comment: next level answer

Answer (score 1):

Use this solution if you do not know the format of the file that you are going to download.

```
$url = 'http:://www.sth.com/some_name.format' ;
$parse_url = parse_url($url) ;
$path_info = pathinfo($parse_url['path']) ;
$file_extension = $path_info['extension'] ;
$save_path = 'any/local/path/' ;
$file_name = 'name' . "." . $file_extension ;
file_put_contents($save_path . $file_name , fopen($url, 'r'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out phpRFT:http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprft/files/latest/download?source=navbar

It have progress_bar and simple filename detactor...

Answer (score 0):

A better and lighter script which is streaming file:

```
<?php

$url  = 'http://example.com/file.zip'; //Source absolute URL
$path = 'file.zip'; //Patch & file name to save in destination (currently beside of PHP script file)

$fp = fopen($path, 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: What if URL is: https://filehippo.com/download_mozilla-firefox-64/post_download/ Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835395/how-to-download-file-using-php-that-has-delayed-force-download