# How to upload and unzip files via php and a url

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I am building a new php cms and I would like my users to upload plugins and themes by entering a url just like we do in wordpress.The user specifies a url to the zip ped file then my php scripts fetches it,unzips it then stores it to a given directory.I thought of using fopen() but never made it.I would just like an idea to work around from because google couldn't help me.thanks.

Comment: Some duplicates: [Need php script to download a file on a remote server and save locally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4504212/1456376) or [Download File to server from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3938534/1456376) and [Unzip a file with php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8889025/1456376). As a note: All those questions are the first results when you search on Google for your problem: [result 1](http://www.google.de/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=2008c0b6840296e9&q=php+download+zip+file+from+remote+server) and [result 2](http://www.google.de/#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=2008c0b6840296e9&q=php+unzip)

Comment: Really thanks.Let me check.