# How to upload file from url via ftp using php?

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, upload, ftp

How to upload image from url to ftp using php?

want to upload image from url to ftp

eg: http://test.com/imagefile.jpg or http://test.com/testvideo.flv

I want that file to upload via FTP or curl php,

I have sample code here but it doesn't work.

It say's no file found.

```
$ftp_server ="ftp.yoursite.com"
$ftp_user ="yoursite user"
$ftp_password = "yoursite pass"
$file_to_upload = "http://test.com/imagefile.png";
$remote_location = "/test";

// set up connection or exit with message
$flink = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or exit("Can't connect to ftp server: $ftp_server");

// login or at least try  
if(ftp_login($flink, $ftp_user, $ftp_password)) {


 // if login successful use ftp_put to upload the file
 // if you upload binary files use mode FTP_BINARY
 if(ftp_put($flink, $remote_location, $file_to_upload, FTP_ASCII)) {

  echo "Success! File is uploaded!";
 } else {
  echo "Can't upload file";

 }
} else {
 echo "Can't login with this user & password";

}

// close the connection
ftp_close($flink);
```

Any one can help this problem? Or anyone can suggest better than this ?
Thank you! help very much appreciated.

Comment: $file_to_upload needs to be a local file on your server if you're using ftp_put.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this case by first read file content from given URL then save it's content into temporary file then use ftp to upload file.

code:

```
$config = array(
   'host'    => '',
   'port'     => '',
   'username' => '',
   'password' => ''
);

function init(array $config)
{
    $port = (!empty($config['port']))? intval($config['port']) : 21;
    $resource = ftp_connect($config['host'], $port);
    ftp_login($resource, $config['username'], $config['password']);
    ftp_pasv($resource, true);
    return $resource;
}

function uploadFile(string $url, $resource)
{
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $tmpFilename = tempnam('/tmp', rand(10, 100) . '_');
    file_put_contents($tmpFilename, $data);
    ftp_put($resource, '/new_file', $tmpFilename, FTP_BINARY);
    unlink($tmpFilename);
    ftp_close($resource);
}

$resource = init($config);
uploadFile(
    "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1b3cdae197be",
     $resource
);
```

More answer about download file from url and save file from another server and create temporary file -> [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url), [second](https://shellcreeper.com/move-files-server-to-server-using-simple-php/), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633728/how-can-i-copy-a-file-content-into-a-temporary-file-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Basically its like:

```
$connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$upload = ftp_put($connection, $remote_location, $file_to_upload, FTP_ASCII);

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection); 


//or you could do as :

$upload = copy($source, ‘ftp://user:password@host/path/file‘);
```

Both the methods worked for me.
Hope it helps you

Comment: Hi it doesn't work, I tested code $connection = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

$login = ftp_login($connection, $ftp_user, $ftp_password);

if (!$connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }

$upload = ftp_put($connection, 'uploaded/', 'http://mysite.com/myfile.jpg', FTP_ASCII);

if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }

ftp_close($connection);