# How can I copy a file content into a temporary file in PHP?

Tags: php, temporary-files

I tried this:

```
$temp = tmpfile();
file_put_contents($temp,file_get_contents("$path/$filename"));
```

But I get this error: "Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string,"

If I try:

```
echo file_get_contents("$path/$filename");
```

It return to screen the file content as a long string.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: `tmpfile — Creates a temporary file` and returns a **file pointer** not a string

Comment: use `tempnam` instead of tmpfile, it returns the string filename instead of a resource.

Comment: I was thinking that parameters list was zero-based

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`tmpfile()` creates a temporary file with a unique name in read-write (w+) mode and returns a file handle to use with fwrite for example.

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, file_get_contents("$path/$filename"));
```

The file is automatically removed when closed (for example, by calling fclose(), or when there are no remaining references to the file handle returned by tmpfile()), or when the script ends. look at [php ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php).

Answer (score 40):

In the example you give you want [`tempnam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) and not [`tmpfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php).

- [`tempnam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) creates a temporary file and returns the path to it as a String.  You can then pass that string into file_put_contents.  You must remember to manually delete the temporary file once you are done with it.
- [`tmpfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) creates a temporary file and returns a file resource/pointer to use with `fwrite()` and other file manipulation functions.  In addition, once the script execution ends, the temporary file created by `tmpfile()` is automatically deleted.

---

Here is your example script using [`tempnam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) instead of [`tmpfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php):

```
$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'TMP_');

file_put_contents($temp, file_get_contents("$path/$filename"));
```

Comment: Attention! In case of the [tempnam()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php#refsect1-function.tempnam-changelog) you need to remove the file yourself in case you need it no more, as it is NOT done automatically.

Comment: @alkaponey Exactly, with a simple `unlink($temp);` you can remove the temporary file.

Comment: `copy("$path/$filename", $temp)` would use less cpu and memory resources.