# How to download a file from server, using PHP Code

Tags: php

How can I download a file from PHP code from any server?

Comment: Check out this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit more?  A link to another page with no explanation isn't really an answer.

Comment: For most file downloads of small to medium size, `fpassthru()` is a convenient way to send the file over HTTP. The code in Example #1 on this page should be a pretty simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Curl to download file from web using php

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
  $c = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
  $contents = curl_exec($c);
  $err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($c);
  if ($contents) return $contents;
  else return FALSE;
}
```

pass url to this function and download contents. alternatively you can use file reader/writer

```
private function downloadFile ($url, $path) {
  $newfname = $path;
  $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
  if ($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
    if ($newf)
    while(!feof($file)) {
      fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
    }
  }
  if ($file) {
    fclose($file);
  }
  if ($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
  }
}
```

[from : This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)