# Download file from Internet and uploading to GDrive

Tags: php

So far, I've built a PHP script that downloads to a remote server of mine a file from Internet, provinding its URL (I've used [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url/3938844#3938844) to download to the server).
Now I would like to upload the downloaded file on Google Drive using its API.

My question is: Is there a way to download the file directly to Google Drive, without using the server? Or I am forced to download the file first to the server and then upload it to Google Drive?

Thank you

Comment: There is an API Doc: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert and I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can 'make' google drive get file from an external location...

However you do have an option to [create a shortcut to the external file](https://developers.google.com/drive/apps-overview#creating_shortcuts_to_external_files), if that suits you.

Also, If you wish continue direct upload you may refer [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#saving_files).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the API doesn't allow to push files from another referer than the one that's calling the API. So, long story short:

First you need to download the file to your server, then upload it to gDrive from your server.

Read here more: https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#saving_files

Or here: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads