# Can I get picture into server from URL with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, graphics

I am in the process of developing my first Facebook application with PHP and Codeigniter.  I am at a point where I have the following information provided to me in an array:

```
array(11) {
  ["urlPic"]=>
  string(94) "https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/s720x720/486147_10151513597963642_1435805055_n.jpg"
  ["first"]=>
  string(6) "Vinnie"
  ["last"]=>
  string(7) "Saletto"
  ["street"]=>
  string(17) "123 Main Street"
  ["city"]=>
  string(10) "Manchester"
  ["state"]=>
  string(2) "MO"
  ["zip"]=>
  string(5) "63021"
  ["plus"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["phone"]=>
  string(12) "555-555-5555"
  ["x"]=>
  string(3) "158"
  ["y"]=>
  string(2) "38"
}
```

All is well and good.  What I need to do is then (within the confines of PHP) take the URL from the value $_POST['urlPic'] and download it on to my server, and then utilize the link to the new file I have created.  Has anyone done this before, and is this possible?  If it is, please show me how.  Please understand that this is for a large ***print*** project, and because of this I am *in need* of downloading the image from the URL as opposed to just linking the URL.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a quick and dirty `file_get_contents() -> file_put_contents()` to grab a file 
off a different server -

```
$newFilePath = '/path/on/your/server';
$data = file_get_contents($urlPic);
file_put_contents($newFilePath,$data);
```

References -

- [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [file_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Checking into it now!  Be right back, wish me luck!

Comment: YOU, Lix, are a wonderful individual!  Thank you!  This works perfectly!