# How do I copy a file from an external server with PHP?

Tags: php, copy

I have to copy JPG from an external server, such as Facebook, to my server.

What is the best way to do so? I though maybe with `fread`/`fopen` etc. but I don't know if it is the best way.

Comment: This should cover it
Along with a few issues
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php). Almost everything you want to know about PHP can be found there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use URLs with most filesystem functions (like `copy`).

```
$url = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png";
$target = "/tmp/stackoverflow.png";
copy($url, $target);
```

Do note that you need to have the php.ini setting [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) enabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $url = 'http://facebook.com/image.jpg';

 $img = '/my/folder/image.jpg';

 file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents($url));
```