# Manageable(errors/status tracking, notifying ) files downloads on php

Tags: php, download, wget, gearman

Very often I need to download various files on my server. This logic should be implemented on php and used via gearman workers.

I'm looking for a solution like wget for php. Could you please suggest something for manageable(errors/status tracking, notifying ) files downloads on php ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download File to server from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)

Has a good set of ideas for you to use. I would recommend curl myself.