# How to download GitHub repository as zip archive using PHP api?

Tags: php, file, download, repository

I am trying to download the Github repository as zip using php api. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
file_put_contents("master.zip", 
    file_get_contents("https://github.com/{group}/{project}/archive/master.zip")
);
```

But make sure `allow_url_fopen` is set in `php.ini`, then you can easily use `file_get_contents()`

Comment: Can we able to download private repository using this code? Also, how to download the tag version instead of master?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine these two puzzle pieces:

php download file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938551/2536029

github zips: https://github.com/$USER/$REPO/archive/$BRANCH.zip
e.g. https://github.com/bpowers/psm/archive/master.zip

Comment: I have private repository. How can i download without authentication?

Comment: I havent played around with it yet, but since the repo is private it makes sense to me that you would need to authenticate in some way. Right?

Answer (score 1):

First, build an URL like using this format:
https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/:archive_format/:ref

Then, use curl to visit that URL, but don't forget to:

- Active follow location (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION), set to true.
- Assign an user agent (CURLOPT_USERAGENT), for example 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0'.
- If the repository is private, use your username and password (or token) to authenticate, setting CURLOPT_USERPWD to $youruser.':'.$yourpassortoken.
- You can use CURLOPT_FILE to directly donwload to a file, just set that option to a previously opened file pointer created with fopen($filename, 'w').

Sorry, no sample code, but instructions are clear enough. It works.