# Downloading very big files to server using php (version >= 5.4)

Tags: php

I have to download very big files in php to my server to process them later. I found following solution using stream handlers (supported by php >= 5.1):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938551/1391074

It's code:

```
file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r'));
```

Question is: should i close connection, opened by fopen. or just leave this as it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that yes, we HAVE to fclose the given stream after job is done manually:

```
$filename = '/tmp/' . uniqid();
$h = fopen($url, 'r');
if (!file_put_contents($filename, $h)) {
    throw new Exception('Xml download failed');
}

var_dump($h);         // resource(5) of type (stream)
var_dump(fclose($h)); // bool(true)
var_dump($h);         // resource(5) of type (Unknown)
```