# Can't get url using JSON script parsed with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I have this link I want to parse some information in it or just save it in a file...

can't do it without this simple code:

**Example:**

```
<?php
$myFile = 'test.txt'; 
$get= file_get_contents("http://www.ticketmaster.com/json/resale?command=get_resale_listings&event_id=0C004B290BF2D95F");
file_put_contents($myFile, $get); ?>
```

The output is:

```
{"version":1.1,"error":{"invalid":{"cookies":true}},"command":"get_resale_listings"}
```

I tried many other things like fopen or include did not work either.  I don't understand because when I put the url in the browser it shows exactly ALL the code (google chrome) OR even better ask me to save it as a file (explorer).  Looks like a browser cookies or something that doesn't load on my localhost ??

thanks for your tips.

Comment: you could take a look into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url but as it says in the comments it may be the php.ini setting: allow_fopen_url set to off which would break the code.

Comment: thanks but the allow_fopen_url is on, did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access that url with CURL.

The server checks if the client has cookies enabled. Using file_get_content() You do not send any information about client (browser).

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.ticketmaster.com/json/resale?command=get_resale_listings&event_id=0C004B290BF2D95F');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: OK... but the cookies are located in the Content Settings of my browser, how can I put them in my_cookies.txt ?