# Disable one of the direct download link

Tags: text, download, counter

we offer some freeware and I created text counter to count the downloads but some of the visitors or web pages uses direct link instead of my 
txt counter's links for example

My text counter's link is:
http://www.example.org/dns_jumper/downloads26.php

Direct link is:
http://www.example.org/dns_jumper/askadmin/AskAdmin.zip

is it posible to disable second direct link but allow the only firs direct link (there are more than 20 links like that)

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking for. Are you looking for a script or server side solution? I think it can be done server side through the sites-available file. Maybe. Otherwise best practice is to always use your php file and not advertise the real link.

Comment: You re right it is a bit confusing , if someone use my first download link with any download manager can see my second direct link too and can share it (some of them have done) , then  my text counter shows wrong download numbers , I thougt if I can prevent second direct link maybe ı can count the downloads correctly

Comment: How does your script work? Simple redirect to the correct file?

Comment: Maybe you should try utilizing some of the functions outline [here.](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.readfile.php). [This](http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm) resource may also help you. Another method can be seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)

Comment: Thanks for your response and links but I dont want to redirect  many links and I'm not a php coder (Confusing) , May be I need a .htaccess code and it can allow only first  direct link , if someone try to use second direct link redirect it to the mainpage