# Uploading image from rest client to php

Tags: php, rest

I am working on php-rest webservices.Can anyone tell how to upload an image file from 'advanced rest client' to php.
 And how do i access the client url using 'file_get_contents' and how do i post that image from the rest client. i will appreciate your help. thank you.

Comment: For downloading file from URL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize the image using base64

Comment: Ok, and how do i fetch the image to my curl-php from the rest client