# Download url not working in Google Drive API PHP

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am having issue with the Google Drive API, i was able to fetch the files using API But i can't download via this link. I guess, must some auth, but i have used refresh tokens to authenticate.Please see below for my code

```
$this->load->library('google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client');
                include APPPATH . '/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
                // Library Files Configuration to get access token and Refresh Token
                $client = new Google_Client();
                $client->setAccessType('offline'); // default: offline
                $client->setApplicationName('xxx'); //name of the application
                $client->setClientId('yyyy'); //insert your client id
                $client->setClientSecret('zzz'); //insert your client secret
                $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
                $service = new Google_DriveService($client);

                $client->refreshToken($drive_data->refreshtoken);
                $client->getAccessToken();
                $parameters = array();
                $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
foreach ($files['items'] as $key => $items)
                            {
<a href="<?php echo $files['items'][$key]['downloadUrl'];  ?>">Download</a>
}
```

Anybody knows how to get the download url with authentication?

Comment: This is having the answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693252/java-download-url-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get downloadUrls, you need to get the metadata of a file. You can do so by using the [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) method. The method will return a [File Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) representation. In this resource, there is a *downloadUrl* property. If you're able to access the files and get the URL already, then there should be no problem with your authentication setup. There could be permission issues where you may not have access to certain drive files, but if you receive no error for it, you should be fine there too. I am not particularly familiar with PHP, but perhaps you are not downloading it correctly? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url) it seems to be done differently.

I also suggest that you check out the Drive PHP [Quickstart App](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2521798?hl=en) to use as a reference.

Comment: Hi Andy, Thanks for your Response. Yes, the issue is with the Permission, i have fixed it by setting the same in Google Drive. Anyway thanks for the Answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is having the answer:
[(Java) Download URL not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693252/java-download-url-not-working)

There seem to be some changes on v2 of GDrive, instead of using "downloadUrl" you may have to use "webContentLink" for getting the download link

Answer (score 0):

I have bumped into the same problem today and just found a solution for my case. I hope that this helps the one or another confused PHP coder out there who also does not get a downloadUrl. I assume that you are working with the examples of the v2 API, as seen on https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference.

First, I have altered the head to not only access the metadata but get full access (mind the **DRIVE** constant):

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
const DRIVE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'MAGOS poller');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', 'credentials.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', 'client_secret.json');
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE)));
```

Then I have **deleted my credentials file** (credentials.json) and reran the script so it authenticated once more against gDrive and recreated the credentials file. After that

```
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
```

finally worked like a charm.