# (Java) Download URL not working

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am battling with trying to download files using the google drive API. I'm just writing code that should download files from my drive onto my computer. I've finally got to a stage where I am authenticated and can view the file metadata. For some reason, I'm still unable to download files. The downLoadURL I get looks like:

https://doc-04-as-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/0B4dSSlLzQCbOXzAxNGxuRUhVNEE?e=download&gd=true

This URl isn't downloading anything when I run my code or when I copy and paste it in a browser. But, in the browser, when i remove the "&gd=true" part of the URL it downloads the file.

My download method is straight out of the google drive API documentation:

```
public static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
  if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
    try {
      System.out.println("Downloading: "+ file.getTitle());
      return service.files().get(file.getId()).executeMediaAsInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // An error occurred.
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
}
```

Anyone know whats going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Drive v2, a different approach (also on [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#response)) is for you to get the `InputStream` thru the `HttpRequest` object.

```
/**
* Download a file's content.
*
* @param service Drive API service instance.
* @param file Drive File instance.
* @return InputStream containing the file's content if successful,
* {@code null} otherwise.
*/
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
    if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
        try {
            HttpResponse resp =
            service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
            .execute();
            return resp.getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // An error occurred.
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
        return null;
    }
}
```