# Get gdocsviewer plugin generated content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery.gdocsviewer.min.js  plugin to read office and pdf documents in a website. The plugin is working fine. I am trying to get the content of the generated preview using jquery

```
var rowcontent=$('.embed').html();///embed is the class of the link
```

But I cant get this to work. Check a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4s8bn/133/

Please advice me on what to do or if its practical. I want to fetch the content and save it as html in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In client side, **it is not possible** to get that pdf directly and save as html in database.You have to do it in **server side**. For server side,here is an example with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url) Once you get that in server side you can catch it with **Ajax** in client side.

Comment: kindly repost the link again. its broken. is there no php solution. am not proficient with Java. especially on server

Comment: see i have updated the answer. I am not proficient with php. So google, if above link doesn't help.But sure u will get some answer cause it's a widely used.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var rowcontent = $('.gdocsviewer').html();
```

From the docs:

> The plugin inserts a the IFRAME for the viewer inside an injected DIV.
>   The DIV tags all carry the class name "gdocsviewer", which allow for
>   styling all the gdocsViewer instances via CSS. If the anchor tag has
>   the ID attribute defined, then the injected DIV tag is also set an ID
>   attribute in the format of ID_of_Anchor + '-gdocsviewer'. See the demo
>   source code for more details.

Comment: Hi @irvin, thanks for the feedback. But I am getting an iframe instead of the html.                                                                                                                                                                   <iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tutorialspoint.com%2Fhtml5%2Fhtml5_tutorial.pdf" width="600" height="300" style="border: none;"></iframe>

Comment: You can't because of the same origin policy restrictions. If you try to get it you'll get permission denied type errors.

Comment: I really needed to get this for my client's app. I don't have a workaround. Any solution would help. and am out of ideas. The documents are all stored in my server. If you think of some workaround, kindly post