# How to download PDF using PDF link with PHP

Tags: php, url, pdf

I want to know how to download file PDF from URL link or another source.

Example :
I have this link : [www.nba.com/gamenotes/warriors.pdf](http://www.nba.com/gamenotes/warriors.pdf) if you click that link your browser automatically read the PDF and show the PDF or you can automatically download the PDF file using third party apps.

And i want to know a PHP code that download the PDF file from that link for example and save it to my computer

Comment: google php scraping and take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is is

Load file from URL  and then put content to user to download it.

```
   file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", file_get_contents("http://someurl/file.zip"));
```

Try this

[Download File to server from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)

http://4rapiddev.com/php/download-image-or-file-from-url/