# How to access the audio file off a streaming link (non-direct) and store it on my server using PHP?

Tags: php, html, file, audio-streaming

I am accessing an HTML page using server-side PHP and the page has a link to listen to an audio. The HTML looks like this:

```
<a href="http://audio.somesite.com/audio?lang=es&amp;text=sometext">
<span class="audio-blue">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
```

While processing the document, I need my server-side script to retrieve the file being referenced in the a tag above, and then serve the file to the client for streaming. I just need to get a hang of how to do the first, i.e. saving the file on the server from the HTML. Taking cue from a bunch of other questions that seemed to resemble this one, I tried this:

```
file_put_contents("myfile.mp3", fopen("http://audio.somesite.com/audio?lang=es&amp;text=sometext", 'r'));
```

The above obviously failed. I am sure there's something very straightforward that's eluding me. Any hints?

Comment: f_p_c requires either a string or a stream resource. fopen returns a file pointer resource. They are **NOT** interchangeable. Plus, that's bad coding. if the fopen fails for any reason, it'll return boolean false, which you then blindly write out to disk. never EVER assume success with external resources.

Comment: You will need the direct link to the file on said server. As @MarcB, you should probably include a catch in there. This may help out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url EDIT: this doesn't show you how to add a catch, just an example of file management in PHP.

Comment: Actually, that's the thread I got the hint to write the statement I did. My only question is how can there not be any way to access content that's already coming to my computer, lack of a direct link notwithstanding? YouTube doesn't give out any direct links to its videos either but that doesn't stop services like ClipConverter.cc from accessing and downloading those videos, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step...

1. [Load and parse the HTML with a DOM parser](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html).
2. Query the DOM for the link you want, and extract the `href` attribute value.
3. [Output the appropriate `Content-Type` header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), and any other headers you need.
4. [Use `readfile()` or similar to **stream** the response](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).  Do not use `file_get_contents()` which will buffer the whole response before sending.