# downloading zip file from url using php

Tags: php

its not about file duplicate,

// not working code , because i assign $zip_url dynamic

```
function downloadZipFile($dynamic_url, $filepath){
//echo $dynamic_url;exit;
$zip_url          = $dynamic_url;
$destination_path = $filepath;
file_put_contents($destination_path, fopen($zip_url, 'r'));
 }
```

// working code but here i assign $zip_url static

```
function downloadZipFile($dynamic_url, $filepath){
//echo $dynamic_url;exit;
$zip_url          = "http://training.costaclick.net/WAWS_1_9/Catalog/4dd946a8-32e6-43b8-a592-6596a4509ec5-out.zip";
$destination_path = $filepath;
file_put_contents($destination_path, fopen($zip_url, 'r'));
 }
```

Comment: you only want to download ? or extract too ?

Comment: @Sindhuja try this `http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/php-download-file-script/`

Comment: @Touheed Khan  i want to download zip file from url example http://testdata/Catalog/d1f87802-be88-4a9b-8765-82d854ec6cd4-out.zip 
yes , i can download this zip file using above code, if i give copy and assign to varible url. if i give dynamic its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File to server from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)

Comment: @Alexander , file_put_contents("Tmpfile.zip", fopen("http://someurl/file.zip", 'r')); yes, this code is working only if i give static url.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code :**

```
$ch = curl_init();
$source = "http://someurl.com/afile.zip"; //$source = $dynamic_url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "/sub_folder/". uniqid(time(), true) .".zip";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

`$source` can be dynamic value of url. `uniqid(time(), true)` will generate random file name. In the we will store it in path specified in `$destination` variable.

**Alternate Solution :**

```
$zip_url          = "http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/download/peace.zip";
$destination_path = "/var/www/html/files/".uniqid(time(), true)."zip";
file_put_contents($destination_path, fopen($zip_url, 'r'));
```

`$zip_url` will be dynamic zip url and `$destination_path` will be location on your local machine.

Note : make sure you've proper permission on destination path folder.

Comment: its not about file duplicate,

Comment: @SindhujaN just try both solutions and tell me output. keep error reporting on.

Comment: @SindhujaN its just a precaution to avoid any issues.

Comment: getting empty zip file

Comment: give me url you're requesting.

Comment: http://training.costaclick.net/WAWS_1_9/Catalog/4dd946a8-32e6-43b8-a592-6596a4509ec5-out.zip

Comment: which method you're using file_put_contents or curl?

Comment: both method i tried its working very fine for static url. not working if i change to dynamic url

Comment: I think your url is wrong, cause i've tried using dynamic url it is working fine on my local machine.

Comment: echo url before downloading zip and try to request that url in browser directly.

Comment: yes i tried in browser directly its corrct url only and i can able to download zip file to local machine

Comment: from where your dynamic url is coming?

Comment: if possible give me list of dynamic urls, cause its little strange that if its not working for dynamic urls.

Comment: iam getting from xml  and url will keep on change

Comment: code is completely fine..issue is in url or any other mistake

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php // HTTP Headers for ZIP File Downloads
  // https://perishablepress.com/press/2010/11/17/http-headers-file-downloads/

  // set example variables
  $filename = "Inferno.zip";
  $filepath = "/var/www/domain/httpdocs/download/path/";

  // http headers for zip downloads
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Cache-Control: public");
  header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
  header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
  header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filepath.$filename));
  ob_end_flush();
  @readfile($filepath.$filename);
?>
```

[reference link](https://perishablepress.com/http-headers-file-downloads/)