# Redirect user to download like without see

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a file in telegram and I want put it in my website with **telegram bot api** . but I don't want to share my bot token. for example **my real path is** :

```
https://api.telegram.org/file/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/photos/file_1.jpg
```

**Note** : `xxxx` is my bot token.

How can I set a url in my website that a user click on it download a file with don't see this url like :

```
http://my_domain.com/?file=file_1.jpg
```

And I **redirect user** to this url **without see this url** :

```
https://api.telegram.org/file/botxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/photos/file_1.jpg
```

Comment: Asking us to write code for you is not what we do here at StackOverflow. Check out this link for information on how to download files with PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url

Comment: i dont want to write code! i want to tell me a way to do this just!

Comment: tnx a lot about redirecting me to this question :)

Comment: May I ask what this has to do with `jquery` or `javascript`?

Comment: yes.you can get real path an change it :|   think first in then speak

Answer (score 0):

You should Download Files from your `Bot's secret file url` to your host and then users download it from `your site url`. the `Important thing` is Your Secret URL is **Secret**

Comment: This way need big host band widthi don't want to do that.