# Can we set the Specific Directory for file downloads with php Code

Tags: php

I have a Url and file name also when i dial Url file downloads in window's Default folder "Downloads" butt i want to download that file in specific folder set by me.

is there any possibility to download file in specific folder with php code??

Comment: if you mean from browser, you can't do that

Comment: It should be possible, you can use file_get_contents function like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3938551/8412711)

Comment: @gimperman this will save the files on the server

Answer (score 3):

If you mean another folder on client's machine (who is downloading the file) then no, you can't.
It would be a security issue if you (I mean your application, on server side) can choose a destination on client's machine as target for file downloads.

Comment: Nima there is no solution to solve this issue. because i want to download file from a url and save it on my server' folder??

Comment: @Mudi if you want to save a file on a server, just rephrase your question and check other answers that already solved that

Comment: Ok Edwin, Actually i am trying this on localhost therefore i asked this

Comment: Are you the one who is "sending the file" or the one who is "downloading" it? If your PHP code is sending the file to a client then you have no control over their choice for download destination. Please give me a little more details.

Comment: @Nima i am downloading the file and want to download it in my specific directory.

Comment: "https://files.podio.com/395416889" when i  dial this url a file downloads which i want to move in my given folder name "public_html/podioapi/abc"

Comment: @Nima Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

So you want to set a default download directory on the client side. 
You can only suggest to change the default download directory in the browser settings (firefox or chrome, i don't know for other browsers) for security reasons.