# saving picture on server - PHP Facebook

Tags: php, mysqli, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to save the picture which you get from the `$FB->get` on my server. So I can get that pic and make it a profile picture when login in with facebook. The only thing now is that I don't know how to save that pic on my server. I think I need to use `copy` or `rename` function from php or something like that. As you can see I tried using it but I have no clue how I need to fix this.

```
$oAuth2Client = $FB->getOAuth2Client();
   if (!$accessToken->isLongLived())
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);

$response = $FB->get("/me?fields=id, first_name, last_name, email,gender,link, birthday,picture.type(large)", $accessToken);
$userData = $response->getDecodedBody();


$fb_foto_url = $userData['picture']['data']['url']; 
copy($fb_foto_url ,'assets/images/profielfotos');

$voornaam= $app->get_klant_fb($userData['first_name']);
$_SESSION['voornaam'] = $userData['first_name'];
$_SESSION['achternaam'] = $userData['last_name'];

$fb_fotoUrl = $app->saving_fb_foto($userData['picture']['data']['url']);
```

How I am making a user based on facebook login.

```
//data ophalen
$klant= $app->get_klant_fb($userData['id']);
if($klant['id'] > 0) {
    //sessie klant zetten
    $_SESSION['klant_id'] = $klant['id'];
} else {
    //klant aanmaken
    unset($query);
    $query['oauth_uid']     = $userData['id'];
    $query['ledenpagina_id']= $_SESSION['ledenpagina_id'];
    $query['voornaam']      = $userData['first_name'];
    $query['achternaam']    = $userData['last_name'];
    $query['emailadres']    = $userData['email'];
    $query['geboortedatum'] = $userData['birthday'];
    $query['gender']        = $userData['gender']; 
    $query['link']          = $userData['link'];
    $app->insert_query('klanten', $query);

    $klant= $app->get_klant_fb($userData['id']);
    if($klant['id'] > 0) {
        $_SESSION['klant_id'] = $klant['id'];  
    }
}
```

[This is what the develeper.facebook looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3736J.png)

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want to save the picture itself and not the FB URL ?

Comment: Also related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url

Comment: @Pogrindis well the link Ill get is a link which when I press it will download the image. So it will not show me the url in a tab or something like that

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the value for `$userData['picture']['data']['url']` is ?

Comment: eddited the question @Pogrindis this is what it will return

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using that url in a `<img>` src ref..

Comment: For example, your stackoverflow profile pic :  `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/70bdb7a2b5ff849d891055490013d287?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1`

Comment: but I need the picture to be saved on the server

Comment: If that's what you need, then my answer and the other will do that. As mentioned I would be conscious of users changing their profile picture etc also.

Comment: I get what you are saying. but what do I do `"your/local/server/file.png` here? what should I change it to in my case and what does the `r`?

Comment: Change that to wherever you want to save the file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php The documentation is important.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL which it looks like..

You can do a save..

`file_put_contents("your/local/server/file.png", fopen($fb_foto_url, 'r'));`

However it would make more sense to me, to store the Facebook URL in your database, and simply use that.. .

Ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: well the link Ill get is a link which when I press it will download the image. So it will not show me the url in a tab or something like that. If I look at your answer it does `r` what is that?

Comment: @helpmeifyoucann the `r` simply means read only when open.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php you're going to READ the file from the URL and save locally. Don't be afraid to test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the curl option to save the image to the server.

```
$fb_foto_url = $userData['picture']['data']['url']; 

$ch = curl_init($fb_foto_url);
$fp = fopen('assets/images/profielfotos/photo.ext', 'wb'); //Please print out the url and replace the .ext with extension returned such as jpg/png
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

//The image will be stored by now
//Remove the copy function

But if you really don't want to edit the picture or something try getting it directly from the url so it will be automatically updated as well.

Comment: Can you make it so the code from you works for me? because I am not really getting what all of this does. (or maybe use comment so I know what to change in my case)