# XMLHttpRequest loads XML from local server but not from external server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

I've made various attempts to load `XML` from external servers, but without success.

**The first example** loads the `XML` perfectly when I have the `XML document` on my server, but not when I try loading the same `XML` from the external server.

**The second example** is loading `XML` from on an external server, but the data that loads on my page doesn't resemble XML.

Am I missing something in my `XMLHttpRequest`, or is this the `Cross Origin` problem?

EDIT: The second example was solved by changing `responseText` to `responseXML`, however the first example already has `responseXML` and yet it doesn't work. Why won't the first example function in the same manner as the second example?

**first example**

```js
var n = document.getElementById("search");
n.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});
    
function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET","https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
    
function myFunction(xhttp) {
var a = n.value;

var xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
const { value } = search;
const foundState = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('title')].find(possibleMatch => possibleMatch.textContent === value);
const unit = foundState.parentElement;
console.log(unit.innerHTML);
document.getElementById("titleNode").innerHTML = unit.children[0].textContent;
document.getElementById("authorNode").innerHTML = unit.children[1].textContent;
document.getElementById("yearNode").innerHTML = unit.children[2].textContent;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="search" id="search"  placeholder="type 'r'" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off" />

<datalist id="searchresults">
<option value="Everyday Italian">001</option>
<option value="XQuery Kick Start">010</option>
<option value="Learning XML">110</option>
<option value="Harry Potter">101</option>
</datalist>

<button id="myButton" type="button"
onclick="loadDoc('https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml', myFunction)">Submit
</button>

<p>Title node: <span id="titleNode"></span></p>
<p>Author node: <span id="authorNode"></span></p>
<p>Year node: <span id="yearNode"></span></p>
```

**second example**

```js
function loadDoc(url, cFunction) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      cFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/kku6-nxdu/rows.xml", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xhttp) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">

<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>

<button type="button"
onclick="loadDoc('ajax_info.txt', myFunction)">Change Content
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: If your response is XML, don't use `responseText`, use `responseXML`. And, always have the Network tab of your developer's tools open when debugging AJAX calls because it will show you exactly what's happening. Also,  be aware of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), which will block cross-origin requests by default.

Comment: Thanks, the first example already uses responseXML, but doesn't work. I updated the second example to also use responseXML, and that one appears to work now. I didn't catch that.

Comment: Your first example calls `cFunction(this);` on `onreadystatechange`, but you don't have that function declared. You do have `myFunction`, but it never gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hunch is correct, this is the Same-Origin Policy in action! Some servers are set up to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), but that is pretty rare. If you would like to set up one of your websites/servers to allow another Ajax request access, you can follow this [MDN guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

**Edit:** Scott Marcus is correct about your code.

About your second question:

I ran your code and got this error in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

w3schools does not have CORS enabled.

Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain) and the links posted there to find a way to circuimvent the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I made that correction to the second example, which is now working -- probably because as you stated some sites are set up for CORS?

Comment: Yes, that is not typical of most websites. I suppose it is called NYC "Open Data!" :)

Comment: So if CORS is not enabled, is there no acceptable way of accessing the XML externally through XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @Scott Marcus that is the “Same Origin Policy.” From the MDN Doc I posted: “Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin.“

Comment: @logoologist I edited my answer to include a potentially helpful SO link for you to explore some ways to get around it.

Comment: thanks for the info. If XMLHttpRequest is so problematic, is there a protocol to simply instruct my server to download the external XML file to my local server?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I did some intense googling on the subject; however, I was unable to find anything like that. You could manually download the XML file from a website and put it on your server. Ajax is the only way I know of that you can load external resources like XML with.

Comment: Or perhaps I could use PHP to automatically download an external file to my server?

Comment: I don't know. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url Otherwise just ask a new question. Have I answered your question to your satisfaction?

Comment: Of course, thanks so much for your thoughts on this issue.