# How to save file on my server link using PHP?

Tags: php, csv, curl, fopen

I have a link to [csv file](https://tracker-api.toptal.com/reports/summary_csv?project_ids[]=226400&worker_ids[]=75647&start_date=2018-08-01&end_date=2018-08-07&access_token=MmNLelZwczlvekVXb2o0dnFVYWl2U2dTaEQ0OEdHNzhGK0hZOFB5b0dENWpQa1U4Z0xGWlhYa2pTaEwzV3FFVS0tSXQrZmdzdTBLTENMUmxHNEZpdklFUT09--0af46f6d677a8034fb89d9d24e135e6604e83870). I want to safe this file to my server using PHP. How can I do this? When I use cURL & file's functions (fopen, fputs, fclose):

```
$url = "https://tracker-api.toptal.com/reports/summary_csv?project_ids[]=226400&worker_ids[]=75647&start_date=2018-08-01&end_date=2018-08-07&access_token=MmNLelZwczlvekVXb2o0dnFVYWl2U2dTaEQ0OEdHNzhGK0hZOFB5b0dENWpQa1U4Z0xGWlhYa2pTaEwzV3FFVS0tSXQrZmdzdTBLTENMUmxHNEZpdklFUT09--0af46f6d677a8034fb89d9d24e135e6604e83870";

$ch = curl_init();
$source = $url;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = __DIR__.'/files/data.csv';
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

I have wrong encoding of the file:

[image: (screenshot2)]

Comment: Are you asking how to save a file? safe != save

Comment: According to your screenshot, that is not a CSV file, but a PDF file.....

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url

Comment: @FrankerZ Yes exactly. I made a mistake(

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, I was right! Thanks
I change /summary? to /summary_csv? and I save the file

Comment: And that solved your problem completely?

Answer (score -1):

I changed **/summary?** to **/summary_csv?** and I save the file