# File copied from a URL is truncated

Tags: php, file, copy, php-stream-wrappers

I have a problem copying a file. My code:

```
$file = "https://www.ilportaleofferte.it/portaleOfferte/resources/opendata/csv/offerteML/2019_1/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml";

$newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/input/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml';

if(copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "salvato<br>";
} else {
    echo "ERROR inport file PO_Offerte_".$data.".".$ext."<br>";
    die;
}
```

[`copy()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.copy.php) give true, the file is created but some lines at the end of the file are missing... the file is 3.6MB and 0.3 at the end of the file are missing...

If I download the file manually all is fine so the source is complete...

I actually have the same problem if I get the file content with [`file_get_contents()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php) and I try to save it in a file using file write function...

I do not think `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` actually are involved in `copy()` but they are 20MB setted

any tip?

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url ?

Comment: hi Quasimodo i tried also with file_put_contents but same problem

Comment: Can we have a look at the contents of the file you are trying to copy?

Comment: sure... well... the url posted is a true url

Comment: Try to download the same file from a different source. I.e. download the file in the browser, upload to your server, use the url of that server. This way you can check, if the source server has anything to do with it.

Comment: The connection to that server seems to be a bit unstable. Maybe you have a timeout problem?

Comment: i have the same issies, try to compress it with `ZipArchive` class before downloading file to avoid corruption. http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to use `file_get_contents` **and forcing HTTP/1.1 protocol**:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
      'protocol_version' => '1.1',
      'header' => 'Connection: Close'
    ],
]);
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.ilportaleofferte.it/portaleOfferte/resources/opendata/csv/offerteML/2019_1/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml', false, $context);
file_put_contents('document.xml', $content);
```

Having said that, I would recommend using CURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlopts = array();
$curlopts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
$curlopts[CURLOPT_VERBOSE] = true;
$curlopts[CURLOPT_URL] = 'https://www.ilportaleofferte.it/portaleOfferte/resources/opendata/csv/offerteML/2019_1/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml';
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlopts);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
file_put_contents('document.xml', $content);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Plea try this connection timeout function,Hope this thing will work for you.

```
$url=curl_init("https://www.ilportaleofferte.it/portaleOfferte/resources/opendata/csv/offerteML/2019_1/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml"); 
$set_timeout=400; 
$newfile=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/input/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml';
curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $set_timeout); 
$content = curl_exec($url);//execute request
if($content)
{
    $copied_file = fopen($newfile, "w"); 
    if(fwrite($copied_file , $content)){
        echo "Done successfully";
    }
    else{
        echo "unable to write file";
        fclose($copied_file ); 
    }
}
else {
    echo "Something Went wrong";
}
```

Comment: Hi Ajay thanks, first your script was falling into "something went wrong" i get the error logs and i got it was a problem with ssl than i set curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); .... file is copied but still cutted... when i parse the xml with simplexml_load_string() still it is not able to create an object from the xml because the format is not respected... tag are missing because the file is cutted

Comment: Sorry then you have to try another solution and when you find any possible solution please upload it over here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem because you use HTTPS protocol. `copy()` and `file_get_content()` functions have some problems with working by HTTPS.
The more reliable way to load remote file is using of CURL. For example:

```
$url = 'https://www.ilportaleofferte.it/portaleOfferte/resources/opendata/csv/offerteML/2019_1/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml';    
$filePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/input/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml';

$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like memory_limit. Try to set it to a higher value at the beginning of your script.

`ini_set('memory_limit' '1024m')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from Http 1.0

This should fix it:

```php
$sc = stream_context_create(['http' => ['protocol_version' => '1.1']]);

copy($file, $newfile, $sc);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the url is SSL enabled typcially additional information needs to be packaged and sent with the request - for the `copy` function there is a `context` argument. The `context` allows you to specify method,protocol and much more to support the request.

```
$url='https://www.ilportaleofferte.it/portaleOfferte/resources/opendata/csv/offerteML/2019_1/PO_Offerte_G_MLIBERO_20190130.xml';

/* download a copy from: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem */
$cacert=__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cacert.pem';
/* define where files are to be stored */
$dir='c:/temp/downloads/';
```

Using the `stream_context_create()` function to build the context for the request and `copy` to actually make the request.

```
$filepath=$dir . basename( $url );

$args = array(
    'http'  =>  array( 'method' => 'GET', 'protocol_version' => '1.1' ),
    'ssl'   =>  array( 'verify_peer' => true, 'verify_peer_name' => true, 'allow_self_signed' => false, 'cafile' => $cacert )
);
$ctxt = stream_context_create( $args );
$status = copy( $url, $filepath, $ctxt );

if( $status && file_exists( $filepath ) ){
    printf( 
        'The file "%s" downloaded successfully. %sMb written to disk.',
        $filepath,
        round( filesize( $filepath ) / pow( 1024, 2 ),2 )
    );
}
```

Another, and perhaps better option, is curl:

```
function downloadfile( $url=false, $dir=false, $cacert=false ){
    if( $url && $dir ){

        /* define the save path */
        $filepath = $dir . basename( $url );

        /* time how long the download takes */
        $start=time();

        /* open a file pointer for use by curl */
        $fp = fopen( $filepath, 'w+' );

        /* create the curl request - write file directly */
        $ch = curl_init( $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );
        if( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );# write to file

        /* the response */
        $obj=(object)array(
            'response'  =>  curl_exec($ch),
            'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo($ch),
            'error'     =>  curl_error($ch),
            'filepath'  =>  $filepath
        );

        /* tidy up */
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);

        /* calculate time operation took */
        $obj->duration=round( time() - $start, 2 );

        return $obj;
    }
}



/* run the function */
$obj = downloadfile( $url, $dir, $cacert );

if( $obj->info->http_code==200 ){
    printf( 
        'The file "%s" downloaded successfully in approximately %ss. %sMb written to disk.',
        $obj->filepath,
        $obj->duration,
        round( filesize( $obj->filepath ) / pow( 1024, 2 ),2 )
    );
} else {
    printf(
        'Error: A problem was encountered downloading %s. The response code is: %d and error message: "%s"',
        $url,
        $obj->info->http_code,
        $obj->error
    );
}
```

The above two methods and also a manual download resulted in a file of 3.19Mb

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at your php.ini.
Probably you have to increase these two parameters

`upload_max_filesize` and  `post_max_size`

Comment: Source file is a https:// resource. Could be rather a memory limit. I don't know how `copy` works (possibly buffering streams).

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

I see this: exec("xcopy $source $destination");

Try that!

Comment: That's Windows-specific, doesn't fix the problem at hand, doesn't work with URLs, and has numerous security issues.