# Converting string to file - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string like `https://filemanager.elo.io/shop/fc1430db9a.ogg` in my database that i pass to my API. In the api, i try to convert the string to file but get the error

**Call to a member function guessExtension() on resource**

**API.php**

```
public function testAPI(Request $request)
{
   //receive media string or url from database

   $media_url = $request->get('media_url');
   $media_file = fopen($media_url,'r');
   $media_file->guessExtension();
}
```

What could i be doing wrong ? Could it be my url is not converted to file ?

PS: New to PHP & Laravel

Comment: Can you dump out what you get into the $media_file obj?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Download File to server from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

Your `media_url` is not a file it's a `string` so you cannot use `->guessExtension()` on string, you can get extension from string like so

```
$path_info = pathinfo($media_url);
```

if you `dd($path_info)` you will see

```
[
  "dirname" => "https://filemanager.elo.io/shop"
  "basename" => "fc1430db9a.ogg"
  "extension" => "ogg"
  "filename" => "fc1430db9a"
]
```

now you can get the extension by doing `$path_info['extension']`

or you simply can do

```
pathinfo($media_url, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

this will return the extension directly, you can read more about `pathinfo()` [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Comment: Well he is not using ->guessExtension() on the $media_url he is using it on the $media_file which looks ok to me.

Comment: `fopen()` will return a handle to the file which doesn't have a method called `guessExtension()` it should be an object of `UploadedFile` class so you can call `guessExtension()`, either ways if he want to get the extension from the file he can get it from the url if the file will have the same extension of the url.