How to read a txt file from a remote zip file in PHP
I tried it but won't work.
<?php
$handle = fopen('htps://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/#readme.txt', 'r');
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('test.zip');
echo $zip->getFromName('readme.txt');
$zip->close();
?>

Can any one edit it as if I can read readme.txt file from remote zip file?

Are you getting a specific error? If so please mention it. I'm pretty sure fopen just opens the file, it doesn't actually read any data from it. And it certainly doesn't save it to a file called test.zip on your server (which is what your $zip->open('test.zip'); command is expecting). You might want to have a look at links such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938534/download-file-to-server-from-url

How to open Inside wordpress-importer.0.8.3.zip I want to open wordpress-importer/readme.txt from remote file

Maybe the problem is simply that you use the htps:// protocol instead of the https:// protocol? A simple typo? Anyway, please read this: What Do You Mean "It Doesn't Work"?

Also the url is to an anchor #

I want to open wordpress-importer/readme.txt from remote file...ok, so download the zip file, and then open it and extract the text file. As I said above, it doesn't look like you've done the downloading bit properly yet. Did you look at the instructions in the link I provided?

Also, if you want to download wordpress-importer.0.8.3.zip then download wordpress-importer.0.8.3.zip, not readme.txt. There won't be a URL for readme.txt because it's inside the ZIP file. Even with thee protocol typo corrected, https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/#readme.txt results in a 404 error - did you even test that before trying to use it in your PHP code?? That would have been a sensible thing to check. Whereas https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-importer.0.8.3.zip will download just fine.

yes https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-importer.0.8.3.zip

I don't see where this $handle gets used.

OK, so adjust your code accordingly to our advice and then see if you still have an issue or not

<?php
// URL of the remote zip file
$url = 'https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/example-plugin.zip';

// Temporary file path to save the zip file
$tempZipFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'plugin_');

// Download the zip file from the remote URL
file_put_contents($tempZipFile, file_get_contents($url));

// Initialize ZipArchive
$zip = new ZipArchive;

// Open the downloaded zip file
if ($zip->open($tempZipFile) === TRUE) {
    // Check if the file exists inside the zip
    $readme = $zip->getFromName('readme.txt');

    if ($readme) {
        // Successfully retrieved the file, print its content
        echo $readme;
    } else {
        echo "readme.txt not found in the zip file.";
    }

    // Close the zip file
    $zip->close();
} else {
    echo "Failed to open the zip file.";
}

// Clean up by deleting the temporary file
unlink($tempZipFile);
?>

Temporary file: The remote zip is first downloaded to a temporary location on the server using file_get_contents() and file_put_contents().
Zip handling: After downloading, we use ZipArchive to open and extract the file readme.txt.
Cleanup: After reading the file, the temporary zip file is deleted using unlink().
